# Tool to highlight and annotate text on websites?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, annotations, highlighting

When I read something I need to underscore what I like, or what I think is important, and to take notices about that read, near on that current paragraph.

So, does anyone know a Firefox add-on or something else (another browser, any other application) which can provide me such a functionality?

ps: I've tried some research tools as [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/), but it is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find a better one: [Diigo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2792)

Comment: Diggo is not free. Is free only for a 30 day trial. It seems to be very good, though.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Wired-Marker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6219/):

> It is a permanent (indelible) highlighter that you use on Web pages. The highlighter, which comes in various colors and styles, is a kind of electronic bookmark that serves as a guide when you revisit a Web page. The highlighted content is automatically recorded in a scrapbook and saved.

Comment: Not supported by Firefox Quantum.

Answer (score 2):

http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/

This extension also has the functionality you're after. It's more about saving pages than simply highlighting some text for mater on though.

Comment: The link seems to be broken (the domain does not seem to exist any more).

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few sticky-note/highlighter add-ons. One of the nicer ones is [Diigo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2792/). It has the option to integrate with the [Diigo website](http://diigo.com) so you can keep track of your important selections later on.