# firefox addon to mark text on webpages

Tags: firefox-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to highlight and annotate text on websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/136856/tool-to-highlight-and-annotate-text-on-websites)

Hey, I wonder if there are any addon for Firefox which enables you to mark important text on webpages, similar when you use a marker to mark important text in a book?