# Programming and Browser Help

Tags: php, javascript, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to highlight and annotate text on websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/136856/tool-to-highlight-and-annotate-text-on-websites)

This isn't a coding question per se however it relates to it. I apologise if it this in the incorrect place as I wasn't quite sure where else to post it.

I am new to the world of coding and as I leap from one web page to another learning about PHP, XHTML, etc and I often find parts of an article , forum, etc interesting. I currently bookmark the pages I like however what I would really like to be able to do is highlight the part that interests me and save it so that when I return to the page again, all I have to do is look for the highlighted part or parts. Does anyone know of such a addon or extension I can use with my browser?

**EDIT**

Be great if the tool integrated with Google Bookmarks or Firefox Synchronization

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you've definitely given me and potentially a few other coders a great idea!

Comment: What you're looking for is called [web annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_annotation).

Comment: This seems pretty close (firefox extension): http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/awesomehighlighter/

Comment: @Paul Zaczkowski - I am full of ideas. One of the many reasons I am picking up coding. Be great to work with a team of developers/coders on any number of ideas I am continually coming up with :-)

Comment: @CanSpice - Thanks. Do you know of any existing tools I can use?

Comment: @ChristopheD - Thanks. I had a look at that but it is extremely slow and doesn't integrate with say my Google bookmarks or Firefox synchronization

Comment: It's not a browser extension, and is not free, but `Microsoft OneNote` is excellent for this.  I have not tried it, but it could be worth checking if `EverNote` can automatically tag URLs to pasted notes as well.

Comment: @paradroid - Thanks. Might have a look at One/Ever Note.
@Mehper C. Palavuzlar - It is similar and thanks for pointing it out. Will go through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wired Marker](http://www.wired-marker.org/en/) is an option for Firefox that does exactly that.

Comment: @jonsca - Looks like what I was looking for. Not sure if it integrates with Google bookmarks though so that I can access the information elsewhere without having the tool installed.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I'm pretty sure it's local access only, but there's probably a config/data file that you can keep with you on a flash drive or email around.

Comment: @jonsca - yeah I read about that about it's rather inconvenient especially if I forget to bring my flash drive like I did today. They do suggest using dropbox but again be cool if there was a tool that integrated with existing services such as Google Bookmarks.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey They've got contact info on the site, it couldn't hurt to put in a feature request ;)

Comment: @jonsca - Will certainly do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: `Google Notebook` is pretty much exactly what you want, but they have discontinued it, and it is now only available to legacy users.  However, `Google Bookmarks` now has most of its features.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/awesomehighlighter/

This highlighter does what your asking of it.

Comment: @Greg Agnew - Thanks. I had a look at that but it is extremely slow and doesn't integrate with say my Google bookmarks or Firefox synchronization

Answer (score 1):

Heres a firefox addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/highlighter/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share your interesting clips with others, or want access to your clips from other computers, you could try out **[ClipMarks](http://clipmarks.com/)**.