# Looking for an addon in Firefox which save the highlight text

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, highlighting

Is there an addon can save what user hightlight on the page and will be automatically loaded the on next time user visit that page again ?

Eg : I open http://www.mozilla.org/ and highlight `We Believe in an Open Web`. The next time I open http://www.mozilla.org/ I will see `We Believe in an Open Web` has been highlight.

Comment: Web pages are dynamic, so this is hard to implement. Why not capture them with OneNote or Evernote?

Comment: a very similar question in related: http://superuser.com/questions/136856/tool-to-highlight-and-annotate-text-on-websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Diigo addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/diigo-web-highlighter-and-stic/) lets you highlight webpages and add floating notes to them. Your highlights are saved on your Diigo account, so you can see them from any other browser or computer, and share them with your friends.

Comment: Diigo is good but I find [Wired-Marker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wired-marker/) is more suitable. Thank anyway :)